# How to reset blinking status LED on Xserver (Early 2009)

Tags: xserve

At work we have received a couple dozen of these Apple Xservers.  The HDDs have been wiped on all but one so there's no OS installed.  The ID/Status LED on the front/rear panel of these servers (all of them!) is doing the intermittent-blink thing that, as far as I can tell, means "There's an error."  This is not the continuous flashing that's enabled by the front panel button to ID the server from the other side.  I suspect it's a chassis intrusion indication but that's just a theory

The LED begins blinking as soon as power is applied; even before the power button is pressed & while the white Power LED is off.  I have tried resetting the NVRAM/PRAM through the keyboard Option/Command/P/R and also through the front panel, using the button next to the status LED to select a function.  No help there.

I've seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55713/what-does-an-xserve-amber-flashing-led-indicate) and that's the right LED, but that question is about the Server ID usage of the LED, and my question is about the Error Indicator usage of the same LED.

I can boot 10.7 from an external HDD <del>but I do not have an OSX/Server disk available</del> and booting OSX Server 10.6.8 to the login screen (I don't know the password) does not clear the indication.  How do I make this LED stop flashing?

Answer (score 0):

#### It means there is a problem detected by the server.

According to the [XServe Users Manual](https://www.apple.com/server/docs/Xserve_User_Guide20080108.pdf) (still available online), on [page 28](https://www.apple.com/server/docs/Xserve_User_Guide20080108.pdf#page28) in the Troubleshooting section, it details what the flashing light means:

> #### The System Identifier Light is Flashing
>
> The Xserve has detected a problem. To find out what’s wrong, open the Server Monitor application on either the Xserve or a remote administrator computer

In my experience, this light will flash if there is no boot media.  [I installed FreeBSD on a G4 XServe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238487/119271) and that alone was enough to make it stop flashing. However, I did have the proper OS X Server install media; you may need that to properly clear the error. If you can get some old boot media, you should be able to get this resolved pretty easily.

Comment: I found one server that had not been wiped, so I am able to boot into OSX Server 10.6.8 but without a password I can't log in.  The LED continues to flash.

Comment: You can [reset the password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/164331/119271)